# Select a list of items in a slicer

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to help a bookstore with its Xmas sales!  I use a PivotTable connected to an OLAP Cube, with a lot of product references, with valuable information as sales of last week, inventory level etc.

I want to display only the data (sales and inventory levels) for the books on a current commercial actions (about 400 books) to check if inventory level is enough.

I have a slicer with ISBN numbers, with more than a million captions, and I want to manipulate that slice with VBA to display only the books I want.

List of the ISBN that I want to be displayed are in sheet "Catalogue EOY", column 3.  I try to build an array with the right slicer names, to be used with the VisibleSlicerItemsList statement, but I get a message "Object required" on that line (last line).  In my example, I have limited the list of books to the first 50 items.

Any idea how I can solve this?

```
Sub ShowProductList()
Dim ProductList(0 To 50) As Variant
Dim i
Dim Sc As SlicerCache
Dim sL As SlicerCacheLevel

Set Sc = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_ISBN")
Set sL = Sc.SlicerCacheLevels(1)

For i = 2 To 52
    ProductList(i - 2) = Chr(34) & "[DIM Artikel].[ISBN].&[" & _
    Worksheets("Catalogue EOY").Cells(i, 3).Value & "]" & Chr(34)
Next i

sL.VisibleSlicerItemsList = ProductList

End Sub
```

Comment: I'd take a step back and filter the pivot it is connected to.

Comment: agree with @user3819867, a slicer is not intended for this. Use filters

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub f()
Dim piv As PivotItem, pivf As PivotField, pivt As PivotTable, ProductList() As Variant, filterrng As Range, rng As Range
'the range where your background data is
Set filterrng = Worksheets("filter_criteria").Range("C2:C52") 'the range where your product list is
ReDim ProductList(filterrng.Cells.Count - 1)
For Each rng In filterrng
    ProductList(i) = rng.Value2
    i = i + 1
Next rng

Set pivt = Sheets("piv").PivotTables("PivotTable1") 'your pivottable, define it properly
Set pivf = pivt.PivotFields("ISBN") 'the pivot field
On Error Resume Next
For Each pvi In pivf.PivotItems
    pvi.Visible = False
    pvi.Visible = Application.Match(pvi.Name, ProductList, False) > -1 'if it's in the range, then make it visible, otherwise hide it
Next pvi
End Sub
```

Not the answer you want but the one you need.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through each SlicerItem and test it against your list to choose to select it or not, here is how :

```
Sub ShowProductList()
With Application
    .EnableEvents = False 'stop executing this code until we are done
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    '.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

Dim ProductList(0 To 50) As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim Sc As SlicerCache
Dim sI As SlicerItem
Dim sL As SlicerCacheLevel
Dim inLisT As Boolean

Set Sc = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_ISBN")
Set sL = Sc.SlicerCacheLevels(1)

For i = 2 To 52
    ProductList(i - 2) = Chr(34) & "[DIM Artikel].[ISBN].&[" & _
    Worksheets("Catalogue EOY").Cells(i, 3).Value & "]" & Chr(34)
Next i

Sc.ClearManualFilter
For Each sI In Sc.SlicerItems
    inLisT = False
    For i = LBound(ProductList) To UBound(ProductList)
        If sI.Name <> ProductList(i) Then
        Else
            inLisT = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    If inLisT Then
        sI.Selected = True
    Else
        sI.Selected = False
    End If
Next sI

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True 'stop executing this code until we are done
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    '.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  It is working, but it takes a lot of time.  I will look for a solution to speed it up a bit.  Again, thank you for having taken the time to look at my problen.

Comment: Glad I could help, I added a few lines in the edit to help speed things up a bit, but it is a pretty slow procedure as you have to go through all items! If it is working, please accept the answer and you can post here for code optimization : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ;)